# Excel 2013 VBA, not calling a sub, intermittently

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am calling a sub from another sub, but it intermittently fails using the same test data, the line that calls the routine is :

```
Call setMargin(marginLines(), product_margin(), ecTot, scTot, ttTot, dsTot, _
                tsTot, drTot, nsTot, sqTot, shapeTot, temp_row)
```

this is the definition :

```
Private Sub setMargin(marginLines() As Integer, product_margin() As Single, _
      ecTot As Integer, scTot As Integer, ttTot As Integer, _
      dsTot As Integer, tsTot As Integer, drTot As Integer, _
      nsTot As Integer, sqTot As Integer, shapeTot As Integer, _
      temp_row As Integer)
```

I have stepped through the macro code (F8) and sometimes it runs the routine and sometimes not, as I say exactly the same data.  I think it runs if a msgbox is called immediately before it but that might be a coincidence.  The routine also usually runs if there is a spread sheet already open.

product_margin is defined as :

```
Dim product_margin(10, 4) As Single
```

which is filled with values that range between 0 and 99

marginLines as :

```
Dim marginLines() As Integer
```

Which will hold a value from product_margin as determined by the code in setMargin.

There is no `on error resume next` statement in the module where these subs reside.

Comment: Is there an error message thrown up or else how do you know it's not running?

Comment: @MissPalmer There is no error message, I can tell that it doesn't run because when I step through the code it doesn't run the routine also the routine should populate values on a spreadsheet but it doesn't always.

Comment: are both subs in the same module? do you have any error handling (try removing `on error resume next` if you have this)?

Comment: @MissPalmer They are in the same module, I don't have `resume next` it `goto` a error handler routine which is not being called.

Comment: well, I'm pretty stumped. If it doesn't throw an error and errors aren't suppressed and doesn't do what it should.... :/ ? maybe someone else can help...

Comment: @MissPalmer thanks for at least making me think about it

Comment: So it sometimes does not enter `setMargin` at all? Are all of these functions deterministic? i.e. if you test each function with the same input it should always execute in the exact same way? What do `marginLines` and `product_margin` look like? Any error handling in there? Do you _ever_ say `On Error Resume Next`? Or  were you saying that that does not appear _anywhere_ in your code?

Comment: I have had a similar problem. I had a complex macro with lots of subroutines that collected information from multiple workbooks. It appeared that intermittently one of the sub-routines was not executed. I tracked the problem down to a faulty statement in a little used path within that sub-routine.  Instead of the code stopping on the faulty statement, it immediately returned to the caller.  I recall I found the faulting statement by deleting most of the code from the sub-routine and then slowly adding it back until the problem reoccurred.

Comment: If I understand correctly, by pressing F8 it simply passes over the line where you call the sub, without entering it or throwing an error?  Nothing happens at all?

Comment: @DavidGM Yes, exactly.  Press F8 -> the yellow bar moves onto on the line that calls the sub, press F8 again -> instead of going into the sub it moves to the next line.